# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with dynamic location path

Tags: spring

I have the following Spring XML-based config:

```
<!--
  These properties define the db.type property.
-->
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="order" value="1"/>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
  <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <!-- contains default db.type -->
      <value>classpath:/default-cfg.properties</value>
      <!-- db.type can be overridden by optional properties in the app work dir -->
      <value>file:${app.work.dir}/cfg.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<!-- db.type should be used to get DB specific config properties -->
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="order" value="2"/>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
  <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <!-- does not work, ${db.type} does not get resolved -->
      <value>classpath:/default-cfg-${db.type}.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

The problem is that the property in the `classpath:/default-cfg-${db.type}.properties` location does not get resolved even though `db.type` is defined by the first property placeholder configurer.

I keep getting the following error in the log:

```
 class path resource [default-cfg-${db.type}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Is there any way to use properties in the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer's locations attribute? I want to avoid using JVM system property to set the db.type value.

Thank you,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both postprocessors are instantiated, orderer and then executed, so your second `PSPC` is instantiated before the first one is executed.

If your first `PSPC` implements `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` will run before the second one is instantiated and will work as you expect.

for example:

```
public class BeanDefinitionRegistryPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer 
    implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        // nothing todo, just to run before other PPHCs are instantiated
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting idea. In the end I solved the problem by implementing a custom ApplicationContextInitializer that activates a Spring profile based on the db.type config value. Nevertheless, this is the only answer I got and thus I am marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Since Alireza Fattahi asked for my code and WornOutSoles suggested the accepted solution did not work not work, I am posting my final solution based on the Spring ApplicationContextInitializer:

```
public class SpringProfilesActivator
    implements ApplicationContextInitializer<XmlWebApplicationContext>
{
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( SpringProfilesActivator.class );

  ...

  @Override
  public void initialize( XmlWebApplicationContext applicationContext )
  {
    // TODO: get your profiles from somewhere (config files, JVM system properties, database etc.)
    String[] activeProfiles = new String[] { ... };

    log.info( "Activating Spring profiles: {}", Arrays.toString( activeProfiles ) );

    ConfigurableEnvironment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
    env.setActiveProfiles( activeProfiles );
  }

  ...
}
```